# MySQL using more memory than expected

Tags: mysql, performance, memory

We recently upgraded a database server from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 18.04, and at the same time upgraded MySQL from 5.6 to 5.7.

Since the upgrade, the memory usage has more than doubled, from ~10GB to ~23GB (which is more than the server has). We tried to keep the configuration basically the same. We have been researching why this might be for quite some time, but to no avail. The work load didn't change at all from before the upgrade to after.

Here is some information from "show variables" that could affect memory usage:

`binlog_stmt_cache_size                       32768
binlog_transaction_dependency_history_size   25000
bulk_insert_buffer_size                      8388608
ft_max_word_len                              84
ft_min_word_len                              4
ft_query_expansion_limit                     20
ft_stopword_file                             (built-in)
group_concat_max_len                         65535
gtid_executed_compression_period             1000
innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size                134217728
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown          ON
innodb_buffer_pool_instances                 4
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup           ON
innodb_buffer_pool_size                      8589934592
innodb_change_buffer_max_size                25
innodb_ft_cache_size                         8000000
innodb_ft_result_cache_limit                 2000000000
innodb_ft_total_cache_size                   640000000
innodb_log_buffer_size                       16777216
innodb_log_file_size                         50331648
innodb_max_undo_log_size                     1073741824
innodb_online_alter_log_max_size             134217728
join_buffer_size                             262144
key_buffer_size                              536870912
key_cache_age_threshold                      300
key_cache_block_size                         1024
key_cache_division_limit                     100
max_allowed_packet                           134217728
max_binlog_cache_size                        18446744073709547520
max_binlog_size                              104857600
max_binlog_stmt_cache_size                   18446744073709547520
max_connect_errors                           100
max_connections                              151
max_delayed_threads                          20
max_digest_length                            1024
max_heap_table_size                          1073741824
max_insert_delayed_threads                   20
max_join_size                                18446744073709551615
max_length_for_sort_data                     1024
max_points_in_geometry                       65536
max_prepared_stmt_count                      16382
max_seeks_for_key                            18446744073709551615
max_sort_length                              1024
max_tmp_tables                               32
max_write_lock_count                         18446744073709551615
metadata_locks_cache_size                    1024
metadata_locks_hash_instances                8
myisam_max_sort_file_size                    9223372036853727232
myisam_mmap_size                             18446744073709551615
myisam_sort_buffer_size                      8388608
net_buffer_length                            16384
parser_max_mem_size                          18446744073709551615
query_alloc_block_size                       8192
query_cache_limit                            1048576
query_cache_min_res_unit                     4096
query_cache_size                             1048576
query_prealloc_size                          8192
range_alloc_block_size                       4096
range_optimizer_max_mem_size                 8388608
read_buffer_size                             131072
read_rnd_buffer_size                         262144
sort_buffer_size                             262144
sql_select_limit                             18446744073709551615
stored_program_cache                         256
thread_stack                                 262144
tmp_table_size                               1073741824`

However, most of it is the same as it was before. We have an old image of the old server (which only uses 10GB of RAM), and ran show variables on both that and the new server, and used pt-config-diff to determine the differences. Here are those (removing things like hostname and stuff that I think would be impossible to affect memory, e.g. default character sets):

`55 config differences
Variable                  showVariablesOutOld.txt   showVariablesOutNew.txt
========================= ========================= =========================
eq_range_index_dive_limit 10                        200
expire_logs_days          10                        5
innodb_checksum_algorithm innodb                    crc32
innodb_file_format        Antelope                  Barracuda
innodb_file_format_max    Antelope                  Barracuda
innodb_large_prefix       OFF                       ON
innodb_log_buffer_size    8388608                   16777216
innodb_max_dirty_pages... 75                        75.000000
innodb_max_dirty_pages... 0                         0.000000
innodb_purge_threads      1                         4
innodb_version            5.6.33                    5.7.26
max_allowed_packet        16777216                  134217728
myisam_recover_options    BACKUP                    OFF
optimizer_switch          index_merge=on,index_m... index_merge=on,index_m...
performance_schema_acc... 100                       -1
performance_schema_hos... 100                       -1
performance_schema_max... 3504                      -1
performance_schema_max... 50                        80
performance_schema_max... 7693                      -1
performance_schema_max... 200                       210
performance_schema_max... 15906                     -1
performance_schema_max... 40                        50
performance_schema_max... 9102                      -1
performance_schema_max... 322                       -1
performance_schema_max... 168                       193
performance_schema_max... 4000                      -1
performance_schema_max... 12500                     -1
performance_schema_max... 402                       -1
performance_schema_set... 100                       -1
performance_schema_set... 100                       -1
performance_schema_use... 100                       -1
query_cache_size          16777216                  1048576
slave_net_timeout         3600                      60
slow_query_log_file       /var/lib/mysql/ip-172-... /var/lib/mysql/dataver...
sql_mode                  NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION    NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO...
table_open_cache_insta... 1                         16
thread_cache_size         8                         9
thread_stack              524288                    262144
version                   5.6.33-0ubuntu0.14.04.... 5.7.26-0ubuntu0.18.04....
version_compile_os        debian-linux-gnu          Linux`

Any ideas on what could be the cause?

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis.

Comment: Post information from OLD and NEW server for comparison, please.

Comment: @WilsonHauck after we fixed the issue, we decommissioned the old server, and don't have the old information anymore. Rick James answer solved the issue. Thanks for the interest.

Comment: If you post additional information from NEW server only, will likely be able to improve your query execution speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set `max_heap_table_size` or `tmp_table_size` to more than 1% of RAM.

Probably wise to turn OFF the Query Cache.

There may be more.  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis

Comment: Turning those down to the default fixed the issue (memory usage now sits around 10-11GB). Not sure historically why that was set so high on our servers, but apparently MySQL 5.7 makes use of it more than MySQL 5.6 did.

Comment: @juacala - Some query might be optimized in a different way.  Those settings control a certain aspect of `SELECT` evaluation.  If you can locate the query, we should see if it can be improved.